# Cannot stop movie clip animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

I have an animated graphic symbol on the main timeline and some parts animated on the sub level, as movie clips.
It's an animal animated from the left to right, till frame 255, and walk cycles on the level of legs, i.e. movie clips.
Im trying to stop legs animation when the main animation stops, so on the main timeline, on the frame 255 I wrote:

```
brTop.stop();` // brTop is instance name for one of the legs
```

Also tried:

```
brTop.gotoAndStop(255);
```

It doesn't work. So, how can I stop the inner timeline stop to play ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if understood all details, but, if you want to stop the MovieClip object 'brTop' on the frame 255, you don't need to write a good on the main timeline frame 255.
Try to go to the MovieClip 'brTop' and check the frame 255, there, add the stop.

```
 //MovieClip 'brTop' timeline
 stop();
```

You have more options like on the main timeline as well, like this:

```
//main timeline
//adding a callback on the last frame of the MovieClip 'brTop'
brTop.addFrameScript(brTop.totalFrames-1, someFunction);

function someFunction():void
{
    //here you stop or add any other logic
    brTop.stop();
}
```

Comment: gPeart, I have no idea why but it doesn't work. I also tried now to place all movie clips on the same layer and to stop it, without success. Could you somehow see my file ?

Comment: upload your file and send me the URL, I'll try to have a look

Comment: gPeart, thanks a lot. Here is the link: `http://ge.tt/7kO5WjE1`. So, the pig should stop walking when it stops moving, it's on frame 154. And if you could explain me shortly your job. If you prefer her is my mail: `qadenza@gmail.com`. I hope it will not take your long time.